# Tag wiki badge suggestions

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, tag-wiki

I know there aren't any badges related to tag wikis at the moment so I thought I might suggest a few.

> **Proofer** - First minor edit to a tag wiki.

Bronze badge, awarded the first time you make a small edit to any tag wiki.

> **Professor** - *created* your first tag wiki with more than x words.

As time goes on and more and more wikis are created, these badges should be fairly rare so it might be worth making them silver.  *More than x words* stops people from writing a single line in a tag wiki to get the badge.  Share the knowledge, people!

And possibly a third,

> **Archivist** - *created* a tag wiki that remained unedited for 90 days.

To encourage (and reward) adding as much information as you can when creating a tag wiki, as well as spell-checking before submission.  Obvious flaw: *Proofer* and *Archivist* conflict a little, users might make any minor edit to a "perfect" tag wiki in order to get the bronze badge.

Discuss.  Perhaps suggest some better names.

Comment: Do tag wiki edits count to the goal of the existing S&W / Copy editor badges?

Comment: @Tim: good question.

Comment: @Tim yes they do ... but further down the line we will probably look at adding S&W which is tag wiki specific

Answer (score 12):

We just deployed "Tag Editor" which is the proofer badge you asked for.

I really like professor, so will leave this open till we get around to it.

Comment: Cool :-) I noticed I'd got this badge when I arrived on SO today.  When it popped up saying "You have earned the Tag Editor badge for javascript", my first thought was that I'd earned it for editing the tag `[javascript]` into a certain number of questions.  The definition cleared it up just fine though :-)

Comment: Creation of a new tag wiki entry is useful, the site can benefit from it. This is especially relevant for the new stackexchange sites where a lot of tags await information. Possible restrictions may keep it serious: the tag should mark at least xx (50?) questions (thus no motivation to create a new tag just for the badge and we support important tags), a substantial amount of words, links, .. if the tag wiki remains unedited for a certain time it would prove the quality of the text even more.

Answer (score 4):

Tag wikis really need a badge for those who pimp it out on every street corner.

It's a good thing to have a nicely done tag wiki, but if it's not pushed out to dance on everyone's dinner plate when they want an introduction to the concept, it's not really getting all the eyeballs of love and appreciation it could.

Make the pimp badges (Announcer, Publicist, P.T. Barnum) applicable to tag wikis and let's see who shares out the collective wisdom hardest.

Game it for champions as well as the tweakers.