# More badges to encourage tag wiki edits

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, tag-wiki

At the moment there's a badge for the first tag wiki edit, but could we do with silver / gold badges along the same lines? After picking a bunch of random tags it seems few of them have decent wiki summaries apart from the really popular ones (Java for instance) and it seems that at the moment there's little incentive for people to create any more.

Perhaps a silver badge for say 50 tag wiki edits and a gold for 100? Numbers are arbitrary, it's just the concept I wanted to get across.

EDIT: As pointed out the existing badges go some way towards this, but it's poorly documented so I'd imagine people just don't know. Perhaps the badge descriptions should be updated to reflect this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tag wiki edits do contribute towards Strunk & White and Copy Editor. So, in a way, if you're a fairly prolific tag editor you actually will get rewarded. It may even be faster for some users to accomplish it in that fashion than to do it through normal post edits.

I'm not fully opposed to separate badges, myself, but I think that in a way, the existing badges encourage tag wiki edits without needing to establish an additional pair of silver/gold. They're pretty steep at 100 and 600, but that just makes every little contribution worth that much more towards getting the badges.

Comment: Ah, I didn't actually know they contributed to those badges!

Comment: @berry Nor did many of us at first, but in researching it a couple months ago we ran across [confirmation from waffles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59329/tag-wiki-badge-suggestions "Specifically in the comments"). It's slightly unknown and inconsistently documented.