# Strunk & White after earning 2000 reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Is it possible to earn the " Strunk & White " Badge after earning the edit privilege?

It doesn't makes sense, because after you have earned the privilege, you can easily edit any number of posts you want and earn the badge just like that.

Comment: What's funny about this question is that before [suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74243/148672) where added in Jan 2011 you could *only* earn this badge if you had the edit privilege.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible.

The "Strunk & White" badge exists to *encourage* and *incentivize* editing. Just earning 2000 reputation and gaining the [ability to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) without going through the Suggested Edit process doesn't necessarily imply that the user is a regular or capable editor.

For more info, see the "Strunk & White" section under [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) (quoted for your convenience):

> #### Strunk & White
>
> - silver; awarded once; same family as Copy Editor (gold)
> - Related to Editor (bronze)
> - Perform a total of 80 edits between questions and answers
>
>   - Edits on deleted posts do not count
>   - Edits to your own posts do not count
>   - Edits to CW posts **do** count
>   - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
>   - Tag wiki edits **do** count
>   - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved
> - Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit
> - Sources: [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges), [Tag wiki badge suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59329/tag-wiki-badge-suggestions), [How will Editor, Strunk & White and Copy Editor be affected by the new <2k edit mechanism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76916/how-will-editor-strunk-white-and-copy-editor-be-affected-by-the-new-2k-edit-m), [waffles's Feb. 2011 announcement of editor badge rule changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#80260)