# Reviewer Badge after earning 2000 reputation?

Tags: discussion, badges, privileges, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Is it possible to earn the [Reviewer Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer) after having got the [edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit)?

Comment: Are you going to ask [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138867/137484) for all badges related to editing? If so, please reconsider.

Comment: Check out the [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/1625565). I think the only badges you can't earn because of circumstances beyond your control are Precognitive (A51 phase is over), Beta (Beta's over), Caucus and Constituent (no current elections).

Answer (score 6):

The same [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138868/137484) applies for the Reviewer badge as applied to [your previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138867/137484) about the Strunk & White badge:

Yes, absolutely, by design. The badge exists to incentivize reviews, regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

The edit privilege won't prevent you from reviewing.

[Reviewer definition](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer):

> 1000 reviews, over 200 actioned